# Unable to numerically integrate a function I have defined

Tags: numerical-integration

I am working with a polynomial and wish to integrate over one of it's branch surfaces with high precision.

The function is:

$$ -z^2 + z^3 + w (-4 z + 3 z^2) +  w^3 (-2 + 8 z + 4 z^2 - 4 z^3) + w^2 (-z^3 - 9 z^4) + w^4 (6 - 8 z^2 + 7 z^3 + 8 z^4) = 0$$

I first solve the associated differential equation to obtain a trace over $w(z)$. This is done with `theCentralTrace` in the code below. Next, in order to obtain precise values of the function over this trace, I solve for the roots over the trace. Then I can compare the trace values to the list of roots and get a more precise value of the function over the trace. As written, I can plot `myFunction`. However, when I attempt to integrate it with

```
NIntegrate[myFunction[t], {t, tStart, tEnd}]
```

the conditional in the code returns an unevaluated `t`, so the call to `Position` fails. The function `getDigits` in the code simply converts the floating point numbers to integer sequences, so I can make an exact comparison to a particular precision (5 in the code). I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

```
myFunction[t_] := 
  Module[{cDigits, fVal,fDigits, pos, cVal},
    cVal = theCentralTrace[t];
    cDigits = getDigits[cVal, 5];
    fVal = w /. NSolve[theFunction == 0 /. z -> rnorm Exp[I t], w];
    fDigits = getDigits[fVal, 5];
    pos = Position[fDigits, cDigits[[1]]];
    If[Length[pos] == 0, Print[t]; Abort[];];
    Re[fVal[[pos[[1, 1]]]]]]
```

Comment: You have a much chance of getting an answer if you add the code for `theCentralTrace` and `getDigits` to your question.

Comment: Have you tried using `myFunction[t_?NumericQ] := ...`?

Comment: What is the "associated differential eqation"?

Comment: Ok, thanks the ?NumericQ did it. If we let the equation above be f(z,w), then the associated differential equation is implicit differentiation with respect to z as in dw/dt=-(f_z/f_w)dz/dt.  Solving that as a IVP then gives me theCentralTrace.

Comment: That solved the issue with NIntegrate but did not solve my underlying problem.  Also, it takes much too long to integrate myFunction compared to direct integration of the trace.  I will post a new thread describing my exact problem pertaining to highly oscillating integrals .